# Permutations and Combinations related to urn-balls problems

Tags: combinatorics

Consider
4
boxes, where each box contains
3
red balls and
2
blue balls. Assume that all
20
balls are distinct. In how many different ways can
10
balls be chosen from these
4
boxes so that from each box at least one red ball and one blue ball are chosen?

[image]

Kindly look into my solution and tell me where is the mistake...

Comment: "*Where is my mistake*"  The problem here is common.  The balls you picked as your "*guaranteed red*" or "*guaranteed blue*" from a box can get confused with your balls that you picked at the end as the leftovers.  Consider a much simpler scenario where we were picking $20$ balls instead and we wanted at least one red and one blue from each.  We know from simple observation that since all balls are being picked, there is exactly one outcome possible... the one where all balls are picked.  Your approach incorrectly counted $6^4$ possibilities.

Comment: More explicitly, suppose balls were labeled $C_{a,b}$ where $C$ is the color, $a$ is the box number, and $b$ is which ball specifically from that box of that color.  Your outcome $R_{1,1}B_{1,1}R_{2,1}B_{2,1}R_{3,1}B_{3,1}R_{4,1}B_{4,1}$ as the "*first step guaranteed selections*" and $R_{1,2}B_{1,2}$ as the "*extra*" was incorrectly counted differently than the outcome $R_{1,2}B_{1,2}R_{2,1}B_{2,1}R_{3,1}B_{3,1}R_{4,1}B_{4,1}$ as the "*first step guaranteed selections*" and $R_{1,1}B_{1,1}$ as the "*extra*" and similar.